# Unable to retrieve data from object

Tags: jquery

I need help with the following code:

```html
<div id="divResult"></div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var jsonString = '{"Fakir":{"firstName":"Bharat","lastName":"Tiwari","gender":"Male","salary":50000},"Pagal":{"firstName":"Nanu","lastName":"Pagal","gender":"Male","salary":90000}}';
    var employeeJSON = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    var result = '';

    $.each(employeeJSON.Fakir,function(i, item){
        result += item['firstName']+"<br>";
        /*result += item.lastName + "<br>";
        result += item.gender + "<br>";
        result += item.salary + "<br> <br>";*/
    });
    $("#divResult").html(result)
})
$("#divResult").html(result)
```

The output I get is `undefined`. Please help me find a solution? Why am I not getting data?

Comment: Can you kindly edit your question to make sense? See [ask] page and go through [tour] for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop `employeeJSON` instead of `employeeJSON.Fakir`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var jsonString = '{"Fakir":{"firstName":"Bharat","lastName":"Tiwari","gender":"Male","salary":50000},"Pagal":{"firstName":"Nanu","lastName":"Pagal","gender":"Male","salary":90000}}';

var employeeJSON = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var result = '';
$.each(employeeJSON,function(i,item){
    result += item['firstName'] + "<br>";
    result += item.lastName + "<br>";
    result += item.gender + "<br>";
    result += item.salary + "<br> <br>";
    });
     $("#divResult").html(result)
     })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divResult"> </div>
```

Comment: Judging by the OP they are trying to get the `firstname`, `lastname`, `salary` etc properties, not the employee names

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Answer edited (just needed to uncomment some code)

Answer (score 1):

Because the `Fakir` property of the object is an object itself, the parameters passed to the `each()` handler will be the key and value of the properties in the object. Therefore you can concatenate them to the string directly, like this:

```
$.each(employeeJSON.Fakir, function(k, v) {
    result += v + "<br>";
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/fgqnevw5/)

Comment: Sir Thanks for your  If I need get all  object like(Fakir,Pagal) and its data, how to modify.

Comment: Glad to help. To do that you need two loops. One to go through each level of objects, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/dvu21zs3/

Answer (score 0):

There is no array in your jsonString variable. Why did you try to iterate this object?

You can do this as follows;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var jsonString = '{"Fakir":{"firstName":"Bharat","lastName":"Tiwari","gender":"Male","salary":50000},"Pagal":{"firstName":"Nanu","lastName":"Pagal","gender":"Male","salary":90000}}';

  var employeeJSON = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  var result = '';
  var item = employeeJSON.Fakir;
  result += item['firstName']+"<br>";
  result += item.lastName + "<br>";
  result += item.gender + "<br>";
  result += item.salary + "<br> <br>";

  $("#divResult").html(result)
});
```

Comment: jQuery's `each()` method is quite tolerant in that it will happily iterate over the properties of an object. See my answer for an example.

Comment: $.each(employeeJSON.Fakir, function(k, v) {
    result += v + "<br>";
});
Its good sir but if I use only employeeJSON and want to all data like object and its element how can I write simple code to find all nested data along with object wise.